# Question regarding practical SLERP

Tags: quaternions

We are suppose to compute the quaternion which performs 1/5 of the rotation of this quaternion:

```
[ 0.965  (0.149  -0.149   0.149)]
```

The answer provided is shown as below:

[Picture of the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIRJY.jpg)

I'm stuck at the second last row of the ans. How do you change from the '0.998 q0 + 0.202 q' to [0.998 0.03 -0.03 0.03]

Answer (score 1):

Your answer omits what $q$ and $q_0$ are. I presume
this is just a real linear combination of quaternions;
in your peculiar notation:
$$t[a\ \ (b\ \ c\ \ d)]+t'[a'\ \ (b'\ \ c'\ \ d')]
=[ta+t'a'\ \ (tb+t'b'\ \ tc+t'c'\ \ td+t'd')].$$

Comment: I got it. qo refers to [1 0 0 0] and q refers to the original quaternion